# How to automatically do web works at special time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web

How can I read a web site's data automatically at a special time? For example, I want my site to be able to read any newspaper's articles automatically each morning. My mean for doing so is reading any another website's data each day automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done enough brainstorming on what exactly you need to implement. I think you need this

Run code at specific time c#

Now google it. Where does the first three links point to??

Once you have this then you need to look into what design best suits you. You can have this timer logic in your server side code , or create a window service which pulls the news feed.

Actually you can implement this without a timer by creating a 'scheduled task in windows'.

Comment: i don't understand your answer. can i run a process on my website host at specific time automatically?